# Video inputs for screen capture

Tags: hardware, diy, video-input

I want to make the Raspberry Pi to be an external capture device for the PC screen.
I don't want to use software on the Windows PC, I want to make the Raspberry Pi some kind of DVR/PVR. Is it possible?
capturing at: Full HD, 60 fps or more.

My first Question - is it possible? Is the Raspberry Pi hardware "strong" enough?
What's the optimal way (cheap and working well) to do so?

Comment: Alternative title: Raspberry Pi Video Inputs

Answer (score 2):

No Raspberry Pi has consumer-grade video inputs. But there are, in fact, solutions that offer high encoding quality and low latency.

However, they're a bit pricey. Depending on who you talk to, some may say they're worth it.

- High definition: https://lintestsystems.com/products/picapture-hd1
- Standard definition: https://lintestsystems.com/products/picapture-sd1

*These take advantage of the Raspberry Pi Camera Module connector to harness the full performance of the GPU.* This frees up the CPU to do other tasks. You also don't saturate the USB ports, enabling you to record to an external HDD for example.

And yes, they support 1080p 60fps on HDMI. There's a sample video on the linked sites.

Answer (score 1):

No Raspberry Pi has consumer-grade video inputs (Composite input , HDMI input, DVI input etc). There are expensive addons which solve that , but the resulting combination is of lower encoding quality , higher latency and less comfortable to use with Windows streaming software and regular PC/laptop hardware than off-the-shelf capture cards.

Simply buy an off-the-shelf HDMI capture card. Such a setup is cheaper , works with more Windows software and is much less hassle.